# bash script - how use a $variable in grep

Tags: bash, grep, variable

I am writing a simple bash script where user input the domain name (example.com) and it greps the email address from whois command output.

I want only grep the email with the same input domain (xxx@example.com).

Below command works if I write the domain (`example.com`) but does not work with `$domain`. I do not know how to use the `$domain` variable within the grep function. Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

```
whois $domain | grep -m1 -EiEio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[$domain]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not expanded within single quotes. In this case, simply switching to double quotes would probably be enough. Also, remove the `[` and `]` around `$domain`.  With the square brackets, you would create a bracket expression that would match any single character in the domain name (but not the actual domain name itself).

In the end, you would end up with something like

```sh
whois "$domain" |
grep -m1 -Eio "\b[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@$domain\b"
```

I deleted the `\.[A-Z]{2,4}` bit at the end of your expression because I didn't actually see any use with it, and I used a symbolic name for matching alphanumeric before the `@` sign.

An additional enhancement would be to replace any dot in `$domain` with `\.` before using it in the pattern:

```sh
whois "$domain" |
grep -m1 -Eio "\b[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@${domain//./\\.}\b"
```

This requires `bash` or any other shell that understands the non-standard `${variable//pattern/word}` parameter substitution.